# Isset does not work with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am making a simple page where user can upload a image without refreshing the whole page. But  `if(isset($_post[oneimgtxt]))` is not working.. 
here is my serverSide Code that upload image :

```
<?php
$maxmum_size = 3145728; //3mb 
$image_type_allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_BMP);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(isset($_POST["oneimgtxt"])){//<!------------------ this line is not working
        if((!empty($_FILES[$_FILES['upimage']['tmp_name']])) && ($_FILES["upimage"]['error'] == 0)){
            $file=$_FILES['upimage']['tmp_name'];
            $image_count = count($_FILES['upimage']['tmp_name']);
            if($image_count == 1){
                $image_name = $_FILES["upimage"]["name"];
                $image_type = $_FILES["upimage"]["type"];
                $image_size = $_FILES["upimage"]["size"];
                $image_error = $_FILES["upimage"]["error"];
                if(file_exists($file)){//if file is uploaded on server in tmp folder (xampp) depends !!
                    $filetype =exif_imagetype($file); // 1st method to check if it is image, this read first binary data of image..
                    if (in_array($filetype, $image_type_allowed)) {
                        // second method to check valid image
                        if(verifyImage($filename)){// verifyImage is function created in fucrenzione file.. using getimagesize
                            if($ImageSizes < $maxmum_size){//3mb 
                                $usr_dir = "folder/". $image_name;
                                move_uploaded_file($file, $usr_dir);
                            }else{
                                $error_container["1006"]=true;
                            }
                        }else{
                            $error_container["1005"]=true;
                        }
                    }else{
                        $error_container["1004"]=true;
                    }
                }else{
                    $error_container["1003"]=true;
                }
            }else{
                $error_container["1002"]=true;
            }
        }else{
            $error_container["1007"]=true;
        }
    }else{//this else of image issset isset($_POST["oneimgtxt"])
        $error_container["1001"]=true;//"Error during uploading image";
    }
    echo json_encode($error_container);
}
?>
```

in chrome inspect element i got this..
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL5pj.jpg)
and this is my js code with ajax...

```
$(".sndbtn").click( function(e){
        var form = $("#f12le")[0];
        var formdata = new FormData(form)
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            //method:'post',
            url: "pstrum/onphotx.php",
            cache:false,
            data: {oneimgtxt : formdata},
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function (e){console.log(e);}
        });
    });
```

Here is html code:

```
<form  method="post" id="f12le" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="upimage"/>
   <label for="imgr">Choose an Image..</label>
   <textarea placeholder="Write something about photo"></textarea>
   <input   type="button" name="addimagedata" value="Post" class="sndbtn"/>
</form>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: add this to your ajax request `mimeType: "multipart/form-data",`

Comment: Add your form html also for better solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your `FormData` as a whole data object not a part of another data object. So, it should be like this -

```
$(".sndbtn").click( function(e){
    var form = $("#f12le")[0];
    var formdata = new FormData(form)
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        //method:'post',
        url: "pstrum/onphotx.php",
        cache:false,
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function (e){console.log(e);}
    });
});
```

> Now, you should be able to access the form as it is. For example if you have any input with name `inputxt` inside the form, you should be able to access it with `$_POST['inputxt']`. And if you have any `input type="file"` with the name `upimage`, you need to access through `$_FILES['upimage']`. So, if you want to do `isset()` for that. You can do like this :

```
if(isset($_FILES['upimage'])){
```

Comment: hy i add  html code  please tell me what is wrong.. i dont have any name withoneimgtxt

Comment: Firstly fix the point I mentioned in JS and then you need to access uploaded files from `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: how do i divide formdata in serverside once i sent by ajax ? should i do like this  if(isset($_post[inputfilename])){} ?

Comment: I already mentioned in my answer. Pls check the last sentence, to know how to access your input file from server side.

Comment: `if(isset($_FILES['upimage'])){`

Answer (score 0):

add enctype on form any time using file inputs

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type=file />
  ...
  </form>
```

and make sure it's always a POST request.
Good luck...!

Answer (score 0):

I had headaches for this thing! you should use `$_FILES['name_of_dom_element'];` in your php code.

Comment: me too..  i cannot voteup u guys because need 15 rap